# Consuming View in EF Code First conflicts with migration

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a Table "IncomingChecks" in my database. I've created it using EF Code first. Now, I've added a view to my database based on this table named "ViewIncomingChecks" using Sql Server Management Studio and I want to use its data in my app using Entity Framework.
I copied the model class and changed its name and added it to the context:

```
public class ViewIncomingCheck
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
     //...
}

public class CheckDataContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<ViewIncomingCheck> ViewIncomingChecks { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

now when I run the app, it throws an exception saying the DB Context has been changed and needs a migration. I even tried to add a migration (which seems to be the wrong option) and when I add the migration, it says that the object `ViewIncomingChecks` is already in the database.

How can I use this view in my code?

#### Edit

My current solution is to have another context just for the views. This way it doesn't conflict with the EF Migrations. Is this the best option or is there a better way to deal with it.

Comment: For the moment EF core doesn't support View but you can work with view using Queries like this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012616/working-with-sql-views-in-entity-framework-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I have done in my project:

- First add `public virtual DbSet<ViewIncomingCheck> ViewIncomingChecks
  { get; set; }` to your `DbConext`
- Now create a migration something called `ViewDbSetAdded`
- Remove all the code from the both `Up` and `Down` method and it will look like as follows:

Migration Code:

```
public partial class ViewDbSetAdded : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {

    }

    public override void Down()
    {

    }
}
```

- Now run `update-database` command and it will run an empty migration.