# How to use views in db first entity framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

i have a question what i couldnt resolve it for 2 days.
I'm working on .NET Core 2.2 by the way and thats why i'm using Entity Framework Core.

I have a views in my database and i dont know how to get view from code side.
Because my views consisting of these;

```
CREATE VIEW table_column as
SELECT db.database_id,db.name,col.TABLE_NAME,col.COLUMN_NAME from sys.databases as db
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as col ON db.name = col.TABLE_CATALOG
```

Someone adviced me these;

```
var rawSQL = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SomeModel>("Raw SQL Query").ToList();
```

and this

```
var rawSQL = dbContext.SomeModels.FromSql("your SQL");
```

but they didnt work. As the last one i tried this;

[how to use views in code first entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7461265/how-to-use-views-in-code-first-entity-framework)

but again didnt work because this is for the code first project.

AS A RESULT WHAT CAN I DO. I am about to go crazy.

Comment: I would remove the EF 6 tag if this refers to EF core. If it is EF core, views are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36012616/working-with-sql-views-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: As linked in Steves Comment, please look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt847184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer provided by Steve Greene is right.

Also In order to use views in EF Core you need to complete these points:

1. Create entity to represent view result
2. Create DbContext class
3. Set mapping between entity and view (Data annotations of Fluent API)

Assuming you have setup those points, You'll perform a query like this:

```
var list = await dbContext.TableColumns.ToListAsync();
```

Let me know if this reply is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much your advice gave me some idea and it worked.