# ASP.NET Core View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am not sure how to get my SQL view to actually be read from the `.cshtml` file. I have my model created to relate to the view and have added the DbSet to the appdbcontext class. I have also done the keyless on the onModelBuilder and created this

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> PreviewEmailAsync()
{
    var myTableResults = _context.WetWeatherReportViews.FromSqlRaw(
        "Select * from dbo.WetWeatherReportView").ToList();
    ViewBag.Data = myTableResults;
    return View();
}
```

Not sure how to get the view to showcase the information within, I have tried multiple different methods and believe the `ViewBag` is my closest one, but don't believe I am doing it right. I am unable to get it to work and not sure what I am missing. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint at `ViewBag.Data = myTableResults`? What's the content of the variable `myTableResults`? How you *move* your data from the controller to the view (by `Model`, `ViewBag` or something else) doesn't matter, just be sure to access the same variable within the view code.

Comment: Do you mean you couldn't get the data from the myTableResults?  I suggest you could post the related codes with EF core about how you set the sql view. Besides, I suggest you could refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52170144/7609093) to know how it works.

Comment: thank you both, going to try to do the break point and look at that answer.

Comment: I think you should share your context makeup to let know why it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I kinda figured it out, I guess it was more an understanding on how to extract the data as @Oliver pointed out. I have this written within `@foreach (WetWeatherReportView l in ViewBag.Data)
                    {` my view to access the data. It is working so far but I am pretty sure I can find a better way to get this to be just a variable I can reference.

Comment: If you have a single (root) object to move from controller to view, you can use the `Model` property. Within your view you can declare at the top `@Model WetWeatherReportView` and whenever you use `Model` variable within your view, you get instant IntelliSense and compiler checks.